# Bigquery - Exclude Current Month rows in a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Can I please get some help with excluding current month data only

I am using the below code but it excludes the same month from previous years as well.
Example: I would like all rows for the current month Feb-23 to be excluded but the below code is excluding Feb-23, Feb-22, Feb-21 etc as well.

```
 SELECT * FROM TaBLE WHERE
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CalendarMonth) != EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) AND
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CalendarMonth) != EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: `CalendarMonth` is a `DATE` type or a string like `Feb-23`?

Comment: @Jaytiger - It is a Date Field with format "2023-02-23".

Comment: If so, would you try my answer to see if it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try below ?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE_TRUNC(CalendarMonth, MONTH) != DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH);
```